# How to create chat app using actioncable in rails-api only project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-api

I am using Front-end is Angular6 and my back-end is Rails. It is possible to create chat app with using action cable???

Comment: yes, its possible.

Comment: Stack overflow is a not a free code writing service. [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and ofcourse read the answer in this question - [Too Broad](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258589/breaking-down-too-broad-and-trying-to-understand-it) to understand why your question doesn't fit in the Stack overflow eco system.

Comment: how do i connect the subscribed messages in angular to rails with actioncable? Should the channels in rails match with those in frontend?

Answer (score -1):

If you have a go rails account you can follow this tutorial series on how to build a chat like application. This can get you started at least:
https://gorails.com/episodes/group-chat-with-actioncable-part-1

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.